# AWS Root Account Resource what after removing account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, identity-management

In organisation on AWS are some created account with Organization root group - we would like remove inactive users from root group. But there are some problems

1. We couldn't search any resources assigned to that users (we try look at AWS Resource Explorer, EC2 Instances, look at also from root account). It's any idea how we can search for them?
2. Anyone knows what happens after remove user from organisation root group? They resource are also removed from AWS?

Thanks for any help.

AWS Resource Explorer, EC2 Instances, Look at it from root account

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're talking about **IAM Users**.

In AWS, resources don't belong to a user, they are owned by the account they're created in. As such deleting the IAM user won't delete any resources (aside from that user and the associated access keys).

If you take a look at the IAM console you'll see timestamps for the last activity of that user which should give you an indication if their credentials are being used in an automated process which you should probably investigate before deleting the user.

Comment: Unfortunately we not talking about IAM Users, we talking about users in Organization. In root group where it's stored main root account (Top right corner -> user name -> Organization AWS Console https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/v2/home/accounts)